# Get data from Personal Data in Identity User in ASP.Net Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a class which inherits from Identity User, like this

```
public class ApplicationUser:IdentityUser
    {
        [PersonalData]
        public bool IsManager { get; set; }
        [PersonalData]
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        [PersonalData]
        public string UserNameBW { get; set; }
        [PersonalData]
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I want to access to `FullName` of current user, how could I do that.

I only get the name by `User.Identity.Name`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You use FindByName from UserManager<ApplicationUser>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom claims principle factory, add your custom claims and register it.

Something like this

```
public class CustomClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> 
{     
    public CustomClaimsPrincipalFactory(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
            : base(userManager, optionsAccessor)     
    {
    }
      
    protected override async Task<ClaimsIdentity>GenerateClaimsAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
         var identity = await base.GenerateClaimsAsync(user);
         identity.AddClaim(new Claim("FullName", user.FullName));         
         return identity;     
    } 
}
```

Register it

```
other services... 
... 
AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<CustomClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
```

and then use it like this

```
User.FindFirst("FullName").Value
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to implement UserClaims

Add your Identity NameSpace

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
```

Then inject it with your inherited IdentityUser class

```
UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager
```

... injecting depends on where you are injecting

Then get current user like;

```
ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);
```

da daa...
there it is:

```
user.Fullname;
user.IsManager;
user.UserNameBW;
user.DepartmentId;
```

all useable for you